# failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with

Tags: svn, access-denied

I'm experiencing a problem while trying to `svn checkout`. I create an empty directory, right-click then *SVN Checkout*. I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with '\\path_to_file\  
Error:  more_path_to_file\trunk', work item 1 (file-install  
Error:  trunk/SQL_code.sql 1 0 1 1)  
Error: Can't open file '\\path_to_file\more_path_to_file\.svn\pristine\a6\a6c521066216c31abc949c92e38229bd0872dadd.svn-base':  
Error:  Access denied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `Access denied`. Your user accounts lacks access to the directory.